# ¿Es seguro dar permisos 777 a la carpeta donde tengo mi proyecto web PHP?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, permisos

Quiero darle permisos totales a mi carpeta lampp, donde tengo instalado mi php. Lo que hice fue:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp
```

Actualmente no me queda otra porque no puedo generar un documento con php usando su funcion `fopen()` sin estos permisos. De lo contrario me aparece "permiso denegado".

Sin embargo, leo que mucha gente lo define como inseguro. ¿Alguien podría explicar qué riesgos supone?

Comment: Primero prueba con darle todos los permisos a la ruta de tu proyecto. Si no te funciona entonces procede con el lampp, hacerlo es inseguro para ambientes productivos pero si solo es en tu maquina no le veo problema.

Comment: La carpeta donde esta mi pagina si tiene permisos, pero aun asi cuando intento crear un documento desde mi editor de codigo con la funcion de php fopen, me tira error, me dice permiso denegado. Por eso creo que debo dar permisos a las carpetas contenedoras. Esta es mi ruta: OPT/LAMPP/HTDOC/yaqui esta una carpeta donde tengo mis paginas php

Comment: No es correcto, pero esa es solo mi opinión.

Comment: +toledano+ ¿y que hago? ¿como se supone que voy a practicar? mi met es crear mi propio y pequeño gestor de contenido, para lo ual estoy estudiando php, y justo cuando llego a avanzado, a la funcion fopen, me pasa esto que me atasca desde hace dias. Si no puedo aprender fopen no voy a poder crear mi gestor.

Answer (score 5):

No, no es correcto dar permisos 777 al directorio donde tienes colgado en internet.

---

Repasemos brevemente cómo funcionan los permisos:

Los permisos que un elemento puede tener se dividen en tres partes:

- 4 = r = **r**ead (leer)
- 2 = w = **w**rite (escribir)
- 1 = x = e**x**ecute (ejecutar)

Y el permiso resultante viene de sumar cada uno de los elementos de los que se dispone. Por tanto, si el propietario tiene permiso 7 quiere decir que puede hacer de todo con él: leerlo, editarlo y ejecutarlo. Si tiene permiso 5 quiere decir que puede leerlo y ejecutarlo, pero no escribir en él.

Además, los usuarios en UNIX se distribuyen en grupos en algo parecido a etiquetas: puedes estar en muchos grupos. Eso permite que además de ser propietario de un elemento, también tengas un rango de "proximidad" si perteneces al grupo del que es propietario.

Resumiendo, la jerarquía de permisos tiene tres partes:

- Propietario
- Grupo del propietario
- Resto de gente

Así, los permisos se explican con sintaxis del tipo: 641. Eso quiere decir, por ejemplo, que el propietario tiene permisos 6 (recordemos, 4+2 = leer+escribir), los otros miembros de su(s) grupo(s) tienen permisos 4 sobre él (es decir 4 = leer) y el resto de gente tiene permiso 1 (es decir 1 = ejecutar).

---

Volviendo a tu pregunta: *¿Es correcto dar permisos 777 a la carpeta donde tengo mi proyecto web PHP?*.

Para contestar debemos ver qué quiere decir: tal y como hemos visto, esto implica que todos los archivos del directorio (y sus subdirectorios) pueden ser leídos, escritos y ejecutados por cualquier persona.

Por tanto, si por algún motivo alguien consigue subir un archivo en tu servidor (lo que estás implementando, de hecho) puede bien ser que suba un pequeño script que sea la llave para tomar el control de tu servidor. Por ejemplo, puede utilizar un script para que modifique ficheros en el directorio. Cualquiera. Sin problema.

Referencias:

- [Why shouldn't /var/www have chmod 777](https://askubuntu.com/q/20105/143251)

Answer (score 3):

Dar permisos totales no es correcto, especialmente en producción. Sin embargo, para asignar esos permisos recursivamente puedes usar:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

aunque no te recomiendo esos permisos.

Puedes dar permisos de lectura (*r*) y escritura (*w*) para los archivos y permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución (*x*), es decir *rwx*, para las carpetas.

Nunca des permisos de ejecución a los archivos de tu servidor.

Da permisos totales recursivamente:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

Quita permisos de ejecución solo a los archivos regulares:

```
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod -x {} \;
```

Con esa configuración no debes tener problemas para crear tu archivo.

pero te recomiendo quitar permisos de escritura en las carpetas donde no vas a subir ni crear archivos con php.

**Una configuración recomendada para Apache en producción es:**

Suponiendo que:

- La carpeta de tu sitio es /web
- El usuario de apache es www-data

1.- Debes tener un grupo de desarrollo

```
groupadd development
```

2.- Todos los archivos y carpetas deben pertenecer a apache y el grupo debe ser el grupo de desarrollo

```
chown  -R www-data:development /web
```

3.- Para el usuario apache poner poner permisos de solo lectura para archivos y de lectura, ejecución para carpetas no asignar permisos para los demás usuarios.

```
chmod -R 570 /web
```

4.- Para las carpetas en las que deses subir archivos,eliminar o crear archivos dar permisos de escritura para apache

chmod -R u+w /web/uploads

5.- Para el grupo development poner s

```
chmod -R g+rwxs /web/
```

6.- Quitar permisos de ejecucion para los archivos el punto

```
find /web -type f -exec chmod -x {} \;
```

7.- Agregar tu usuario y todos los necesarios al grupo desarrollo .

```
groups username

usermod -G development username
```

8.- Agregar umask en el profile para los usuarios que se conecten por ssh `/home/user/.profile`

```
umask 0002
```

9.- Si usas sftp para subir archivos al servidor agrega el umask en la linea subsystem del archivo de configuracion de sshd `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -u 0002
```

En el punto 3 y 5 los archivos quedan con permisos de ejecución pero el punto 6 lo soluciona

En el punto 7 con considerar que si el usuario tiene otros grupos agregarlos en usermod separados por comas la salida del groups te dirá que grupos mantener

```
usermod -G otrogrupo,development,... username
```

Comment: Hola. La situación es así: Estoy practicando con un lenguaje de programación llamado php. Quiero generar un documento con una función de ee lenguaje llamada FOPEN, pero cuando lo intento me aparece un mensaje "permiso denegado", y la razón es que la carpeta donde está mi servidor php no permite que yo cree documentos, por eso quiero darle permisos. Mi página está dentro de la carpeta HTDOCS (que si tiene permisos) que esta dentro de la carpeta LAMPP, que esta dentro de la carpeta OPT. Yo quuiero sarle permisos totales a la carpeta LAMPP para que me permita crear documetnos con la funcion fopen

Comment: solucion facil **chmod -R 777 rutaLAMPP** donde rutaLAMPP es el PATH de la carpeta LAMPP

Comment: Ya lo hice co tu comando, gracias (sudo chmod -r 777 /opt/lampp). Lo malo es que ahora cualquiera podria eliminar las carpetas, pero bueno, solo yo uso mi maquina, y al menos con esto ya podre practicar para llegar a mi meta que es crear mi propio gestor (no comercial sino para mi) Gracias a todos los otros que comentaron tambien.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco por qué es malo dar 777? Insistes -correctamente- en que es malo, pero sería bueno explicar el porqué en la respuesta.

Comment: Ya te lo han explicado, dar permisos 777 significa que un atacante puede tomar el control de tu ordenador, TOTALMENTE! Por ejemplo, pueden subir un shell en php (https://github.com/b374k/b374k por ejemplo) y lanzarlo, con lo que luego pueden robarte fotos, subir troyanos, ejecutarlos, atacar otros ordenadores de la red interna... es un caramelito para una mala persona.