# Problema con liga simbólica en servidor de producción

Tags: php, laravel, linux

Tengo un proyecto en producción en DOM Cloud, el proyecto se supone que almacena imagenes y las muestra.
En el proyecto (laravel) esta la carpeta donde se almacenan las imágenes `/storage/app/public/imamgenes/foto1.jpg` entonces para poderlas mostrar hay que crear la liga simbólica en la carpeta `/public`
y la ruta para la imagen dentro de la carpeta public quedaría `/storage/imagenes/foto1.jpg`. En el entorno de desarrollo el proyecto funciona correctamente sin embargo en el de producción por alguna razón las imágenes saltan el error de 404 not found. El servidor de producción si almacena las imágenes en los directorios correctos pero al momento de mostrar la imagen es cuando salta el error. Ya ejecute el comando de `php artisan storage:link` en el servidor de producción, También verifique los permisos de la carpeta public ejecutando el comando `chmod 777 -R public` pero no logro hacer que funcione.

Comment: Verifica la URL de tu archivo .env. También valida que las rutas que almacenas estén correctas.

Comment: Si ya cheque que las rutas de la bd estén correctas y la url del .env también. Por eso se me hace muy extraño

Comment: Si no me equivoco los permisos son a la carpeta `Storage`, no a la `public`. Prueba con este permiso -> `sudo chown -R www-data: storage`

Comment: Si, al parecer el servidor no podia acceder a la carpeta storage no me dejo ejecutar el chown pero en vez utilize el chmod 777 -R storage y se soluciono el problema. Muchas gracias

Answer (score -2):

ejecutar el comando `chmod 777 -R storage` soluciono el problema

Comment: [¿Es seguro dar permisos 777 a la carpeta donde tengo mi proyecto web PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/111529)

Comment: 777 es el número del diablo en un servidor conectado a internet.  No hagan esto!

Comment: trate de ejecutar chown -R www-data storage pero no existe el usuario, no se que usuario usa el hosting, estoy usando DOMcloud, alguna idea?

Comment: Depende del sistema operativo, que servidor está usando y como esté configurado. No podemos saberlo nos, pregunta a soporte o investiga eso... por ejemplo para nginx busca algo así https://serverfault.com/questions/1076157/who-is-the-web-server-user-in-nginx