# no puedo dar permisos de laravel.log en los archivos de registro en MAC M2

Tags: laravel, visual-studio, xampp, macos

mi nombre es david y estudio ingenieria de software, estoy trabajando en un proyecto con laravel y visual studio code, pero al momento de acceder a los visuales del proyecto con local host, me arroja un error donde laravel no tiene permiso para escribir en los archivos de registro de laravel.log ni en los archivos de vistas, he estado buscando una solucion pero no la encuentro, cabe aclarar que soy MAC con chip de Apple Silicon, he intentado con los siguientes codigos pero no parece corregir el error:

chmod -R 775 storage

chown -R usuario:grupo storage

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendrías que saber cual usuario usa tu servidor para darle los permisos , dependiendi de que servidor y como está configurado podría ser `www-data` , `http` u otro. Luego podrás darle la propiedad del directorio con `chown -R miUsuario:www-data storage` en el caso que sea ese el nombre

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Después de estar buscando ayuda con la pregunta planteada, leyendo en diferentes medios he logrado encontrar el código para poder arreglar el problema y es el siguiente:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/proyecto
chmod -R 777 storage
```

para cualquiera que le pueda servir en el futuro.
*recordar que este me funciono a mí en MAC OS VENTURA CON EL CHIP APPLE SILICON M2
*Recordar que cada vez que se haga un proyecto con laravel se debe volver a dar permisos al nuevo proyecto, desde el terminal con el codigo proporcionado anteriormente sin dar sudo de super usuario, solo chmod

Comment: En sistemas operativos basados en unix o en gnu/linux requieres permisos de nivel administrador para modificar los permisos de archivos y directorios. la palabra sudo antes del comando chmod especifica que los comandos deben de ser ejecutados como superusuario. Aparte de esos comandos existen otros que descubrirás conforme los vayas requiriendo. No es recomendable convertir tu usuario en superusuario, basta con que forme parte de la lista "suoders"

Comment: [¿Es seguro dar permisos 777 a la carpeta donde tengo mi proyecto web PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/111529)